# Distribute arbitrary rows on multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, data-entry

I have a table of materials.
I need to fill a data entry form from that table.

The problem is that the data entry form is divided into multiple columns each one containing a a number of materials as in the picture.
[image]
How to write a tsql select query to obtain the first bunch of material names into a column, the second bunch into a second column and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be easiest to do this in the client side, and not in the database, but if you really want to do this, I would assume the simplest way to distribute rows into 3 groups is to use row_number() with modulo 3 and build separate columns using that. That will order the rows slightly differently:

```
A    B    C
D    E    F
G    H
```

If you need to have them in the other order, then you need to divide the row_number() with the number of rows divided by 3. That will you get them in the order

```
A    D    G
B    E    H
C    F
```

Example:

```
select
  max(case when GRP = 0 then VALUE end),
  max(case when GRP = 1 then VALUE end),
  max(case when GRP = 2 then VALUE end)
from
(
    select 
      (row_number() over (order by VALUE)-1) % 3 as GRP, 
      (row_number() over (order by VALUE)-1) / 3 as ROW, 
      VALUE
    from table1
)X
group by ROW
```

Example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3421c/1)

Edit: Example how to divide the rows the other way:

```
declare @NOLINES int
select @NOLINES = ceiling(count(*) / 3.0) from table1

select
  max(case when GRP = 0 then VALUE end),
  max(case when GRP = 1 then VALUE end),
  max(case when GRP = 2 then VALUE end)
from
(
    select 
      (row_number() over (order by VALUE)-1) / @NOLINES as GRP, 
      (row_number() over (order by VALUE)-1) % @NOLINES as ROW, 
      VALUE
    from table1
)X
group by ROW
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Would you give another example to show the rows in the other way as in the question?

Comment: You just need to have the number of rows + swap modulo and division the other way. Added example for that.