# How to convert matrix data into columns

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

hi i have thousands records in a signle column of my oracle database table like this

[image]

I want to display data in 4 columns with the help of  SQL query
here is my desire results
[image]

so in this example, I have a total 24 records and I want to display 6 records each column

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Is there a condition defining which number goes to which column?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Distribute arbitrary rows on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34973457/distribute-arbitrary-rows-on-multiple-columns)

Comment: @PavelSmirnov no condition just want to equal data goes in each column

Comment: @Makdous no sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT A, B, C, D
FROM   (
  SELECT value,
         MOD( ROWNUM - 1, 4 ) AS col,
         CEIL( ROWNUM / 4 ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name
)
PIVOT( MAX( value ) FOR col IN (
  0 AS A,
  1 AS B,
  2 AS C,
  3 AS D
) )
ORDER BY rn;
```

So if your data is:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1,1000))
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 25;
```

Then it outputs:

> ```
>   A |    B |    C |    D
> --: | ---: | ---: | ---:
> 754 |  622 |  265 |  181
> 566 |  801 |  844 |  320
> 938 |  377 |  919 |  306
> 921 |  402 |  737 |  143
> 562 |   94 |  868 |  790
> 617 |  809 |  437 |  469
> 264 | null | null | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3f7d8f27480fa6cd0156d92fe3cf12da)*